# Negative values and postive values in excel

Tags: excel

If there are negative values and postive values in excel

For example: In a Column there are values greater than 0, and less than 0

**I want** a condition, where I get:

1. the values less than 0 as one value
2. the values less than or equal to 3 as other value
3. greater than 3 as other value

Comment: Please add what you have tried to do?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your value is in A1, you can use the formula

```
=IF(A1<0;"negative";IF(A1<=3;"small";"big"))
```

the generic formula is

```
=IF( ..condition.. ; ..then.. ; ..else.. )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these (I'm assuming you want the sum of all these values):

the values less than 0 as one value

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"<0")
```

the values less than or equal to 3 as other value

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,C:C,">=0",C:C,"<=3")
```

greater than 3 as other value

```
=SUMIF(C:C,">3")
```